# Can the law of total covariance apply to variables from different sample spaces?

Tags: probability, covariance, covariance-matrix

Wikipedia says this about the law of total covariance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance):

> In probability theory, the law of total covariance,[1] covariance decomposition formula, or ECCE states that if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are random variables on the same probability space, and the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is finite, then
>
> $\text{cov}(X,Y)=E(\text{cov}(X,Y∣Z))+\text{cov}(E(X∣Z),E(Y∣Z))$.

It says the following about probability spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space):

> A probability space consists of three parts:[1][2]
>
> 1. A sample space, $Ω$, which is the set of all possible outcomes.
> 2. A set of events $\scriptstyle \mathcal{F}$, where each event is a set containing zero or more outcomes.
> 3. The assignment of probabilities to the events; that is, a function $P$ from events to probabilities.

I was not aware of the requirement that the random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ must share the same probability space and, in particular, a sample space.

Is this always true and, if so, why? A proof, or even some examples, showing that the law fails when the variables have different sample spaces would be much appreciated.

Comment: Even if $X, Y, Z$ are defined on three different sample spaces $\Omega_X, \Omega_Y, \Omega_Z$, as soon as you to start talking of their _joint_ behavior (which you are doing as soon as you mention the word _covariance_), you are, in effect, defining these variables  on the product sample space $\Omega_X \times \Omega_Y \times \Omega_Z$. If the product _measure_ is the product of the individual measures, then the covariances are $0$ and the whole calculation of ECCE is trivial.

Comment: You cannot even talk about a joint distribution (thus a covariance) if your variables are not defined on the same sample space!  And, that is a very technical point which NEVER (maybe except in quantum mecanics ...) creates problems.  You dont need to think about it!

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate and kjetil. I see my mistake: they are on the same product sample space $\Omega_X \times \Omega_Y \times \Omega_Z$, even when $\Omega_X$,$\Omega_Y$, and $\Omega_Z$ are three different sample spaces. Thanks.